# Getting Stream closed when reading/writing to file Java

Tags: java, file

I'm implementing a small tool in Java. I have a excel document and from every sheet I need to generate a .sql file. I've created an sql file model, which I have to read from for every excel sheet then replace a value and write it back to another .sql file. The problem is I use a for where I loop through my sheets and for every sheet I need to read that sql file, modify it and export it somewhere else. I get a "Stream closed" error, and I don't know how to close my buffer and/or my InputStream properly. Can you guys help me out with this ?

This is my code:
This gets everything from the file and converts it to a String

```
public String getString(InputStream is) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + System.lineSeparator());
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
return sb.toString();
}
```

This is used to export the file

```
public void exportFile(String text, String path, String name, String extension) {

    BufferedWriter output = null;

    try {
        File sqlFile = new File(path + name + extension);
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(sqlFile));
        output.write(text);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.severe("Unable to write to file!\n");
    } finally {
        if (output != null) {
            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                logger.severe("Unable to close buffer\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this a the part of my `run()` method, which uses the code above:

```
    ClassLoader loader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    InputStream createTableInputStream = loader.getResourceAsStream("val_table_create.sql");

    if (createTableInputStream == null) {
        logger.severe("No tempalte found for creating table!\n");
        return;
    }

    List<Sheet> bookSheets = getSheets(book);

    for (Sheet sheet : bookSheets) {
        setHeader(table, sheet);

        String exportText = getString(createTableInputStream);
        exportText = exportText.replaceAll(TABLE_NAME, tableName);
        // exportText = exportText.replaceAll(VAL_DATA_TYPE, valDataType);
        // exportText = exportText.replaceAll(MSG_TEXT_DATA_TYPE, messageDataType);
        exportFile(exportText, absoluteWorkspacePath + File.separator + outputPath + File.separator, tableName, ".sql");
    }

    if (createTableInputStream != null) {
        createTableInputStream.close();
    }
```

Comment: _Please_ use Java 7 `try-with-resources`; the manual resource handling in this code makes it almost incomprehensible. And `createTableInputStream` is not closed at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is in this method:

```
public String getString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
```

You close the the reader and stream at the end. (When you close the reader the streams in it are automatic close.

Edit: You should close the reader. `getString(InputStream is) throws IOException` returns always the same String or? Read it before you go in the loop and reuse the String everytime.

```
String exportText = getString("val_table_create.sql");
for (Sheet sheet : bookSheets) {
    setHeader(table, sheet);        
    String newExportText = exportText.replaceAll(TABLE_NAME, tableName);
  messageDataType);
    exportFile(newExportText, absoluteWorkspacePath + File.separator + outputPath + File.separator, tableName, ".sql");
}
```

Change your getString Method to this:

```
public String getString(String resourceName) throws IOException {

BufferedReader reader = null;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;

try {
        InputStream createTableInputStream reader.getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + System.lineSeparator());
    }

} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
return sb.toString();
}
```

and close there all the streams. Now you have one place where you load your file.

Comment: I've deleted them from my `getString()` method. The error does not apear anymore, but my file is empty, I assume because the `InputStream` is not closed. I've edited my code and I tried to close it like that, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`createTableInputStream` will be closed for the first time you call `getString` method so for next sheet in loop you will get stream closed.

It's a better practice to close the stream in the method who created it. You should close the stream in `run` method instead.

Comment: I've edited my code, and I've tried to close it like that, but it didn't work.

Comment: @OlarAndrei You cannot re-read from `InputStream` but you can use `mark` and `reset` method.